# How to sample vertex color in geometry nodes from a mesh onto another?

Tags: geometry-nodes, vertex-colors

I've been trying to sample the (vertex) color of the grass from a plane which has been vertex painted, from what I could gather this should be done with attributes in the geometry node editor, I'm a total newbie in geometry nodes but I could get it to output the color attribute, the problem is sampling from the plane, is it even possible?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The fix was the use of *Named Attribute Node*. To achieve the proximity-based transfer I used the node tree in the image below. I just fed the named attribute node in the transfer attribute node to get the vertex color.

[image]